# Negative accuracy score in regression models with Scikit-Learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I wrote a code that predicts house prices. The problem is, Im getting negative accuracy score.
I have used 5 different algorithms and accuracy score is all  over the place.

The first problem that I have is that I get a warning when I'm using `.map` function, but I do not think thats a problem here.

The regression models work , but their train and test accuracy are all over the place.
I have also tried this:

`from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
...
score_train = regression.accuracy_score(variables_train, result_train)
...`

but It showed me this AttributeError: 'LinearRegression' object has no attribute 'accuracy_score'

You can download the database from here:

https://www.sendspace.com/file/93nkdy

This is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#pandas display options
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 70)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 100)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

data = pd.read_csv("validate.csv")
data = data.drop(columns = ["id"])

data = data.dropna(axis='columns')

data_for_pred = data[["bedrooms_total", "baths_total",
                        "sq_ft_tot_fn", "garage_capacity",
                        "city", "total_stories", "rooms_total",
                        "garage", "flood_zone","price_closed"]]

#to see how many different values I have 
cities =  data_for_pred['city'].unique()
garage = data_for_pred['garage'].unique()
flood_zone = data_for_pred['flood_zone'].unique()

#mapping so that I can do my regression
data_for_pred['city'] = data_for_pred['city'].map({'Woodstock': 1, 'Barnard': 2, 'Pomfret': 3})
data_for_pred['garage'] = data_for_pred['garage'].map({'No': 0, 'Yes': 1})
data_for_pred['flood_zone'] = data_for_pred['flood_zone'].map({'Unknown': 0, 'Yes': 1, 'No': -1})

#print(data_for_pred)

def regression_model(bedrooms_num, baths_num, sq_ft_tot, garage_cap,
                    city, total_stor, rooms_tot, garage, flood_zone):


    classifiers = [
        ["Linear regression", linear_model.LinearRegression()],
        ["Support vector regression", SVR(gamma = 'auto')],
        ["Decision tree regression", DecisionTreeRegressor()],
        ["SVR - RBF", SVR(kernel = "rbf", C = 1e3, gamma = 0.1)],
        ["SVR - Linear regression", SVR(kernel = "linear", C = 1e0)]]

    variables = data_for_pred.iloc[:,:-1]
    results = data_for_pred.iloc[:,-1]

    predictionData = [bedrooms_num, baths_num, sq_ft_tot, garage_cap, city,
                      total_stor, rooms_tot, garage, flood_zone]

    info = ""

    for item in classifiers:

        regression = item[1]

        variables_train, variables_test, result_train, result_test = train_test_split(variables, results , test_size = 0.2, random_state = 4)

        regression.fit(variables_train, result_train)

        #Prediction
        prediction = regression.predict([predictionData])
        prediction = round(prediction[0], 2)

        #Accuracy of prediction
        score_train = regression.score(variables_train, result_train)
        score_train = round(score_train*100, 2)

        score_test = regression.score(variables_test, result_test)
        score_test = round(score_test*100, 2)

        info += str(item[0]) + " prediction: " + str(prediction) + " | Train accuracy: " + str(score_train) + "% | Test accuracy: " + str(score_test) + "%\n"

    return info


print(regression_model(7, 8, 4506, 0, 1, 2.00, 15, 0, 0)) #true value 375000
print(regression_model(8, 8, 5506, 0, 1, 2.00, 15, 0, 0)) #true value more then 375000
```

Comment: @anky_91 How can this be a duplicate?
Its the whole other question

Comment: `data_for_pred` is a slice of the other df `data` fix that with the dupe link, this is a dupe according to the warning, `"A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame."`

Comment: This is the question about accuracy score

Comment: The question might be titled about an accuracy score but they're asking about a pandas issue.

Comment: No, Im asking about accuracy score!
This does not have anythong to do with pandas issue.

Comment: @taga since you edited now, removing the vote, please be specific about what you ask

Comment: Right, and the reason you posted the warning you got is...?

Comment: Here, I deleted the warning. I posted it because I want people to see what my program is showing, maybe that can be a problem that I have with accuracy.

Answer (score 10):

***The accuracy is defined for classification problems.
Here you have a regression problem.***

The `.score` method of the `LinearRegression` returns the coefficient of determination R^2 of the prediction **not the accuracy.**

> score(self, X, y[, sample_weight])    Returns the coefficient of
>   determination R^2 of the prediction.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html

**EDIT**

You can use this **IF YOU PREDICT LABELS (CLASSIFICATION problem)**.

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score  
scores_classification = accuracy_score(result_train, prediction)
```

**IF YOU PREDICT SCALAR VALUES (REGRESSION problem)- this is your case** you should use regression metrics like:

```
scores_regr = metrics.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)
```

All regression scoring methods are here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics

**EDIT 2**

Use:

```
score_train = mean_squared_error(result_train, prediction)
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to calculate the accuracy?
I have tried to use `from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score` but it shows me error. I tried `score_train = regression.accuracy_score(variables_train, result_train)` but It showed me this `AttributeError: 'LinearRegression' object has no attribute 'accuracy_score'
`

Comment: @taga Accuracy is classification metric, it makes no sense to use it with regression.

Comment: @serafeim  Ok, I imported `from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error 
` . So I do not need to split my data into test and train?
Also, whats my y_true, y_pred?

Comment: Can you please implement your solution in my code?
I have tried it , but i do not mange to make it work. I also tried your accuracy_score for classification problem (I have tried it on one other example) but it gives me this error `ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of continuous-multioutput and binary targets`

Comment: you do not have a classification problem. You have a regression problem so `accuracy_score ` will never work. You need to use `mean_squared_error ` or other regression evaluation metric

Comment: use `from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error`. `y_true` should be the true values (that is, the `result_train, result_test`)and `y_pred` the predictions of the model (that is, the variable `prediction`)

Comment: @taga you should visit https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ , which will help you understand more about Machine Learning

Comment: @serafeim I have tried to use `from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error` , and then `input_values = [14, 2]
prediction = regression.predict([input_values])
accuracy_regression = mean_squared_error(var_test, prediction)` but I always get an error `ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 1]`

Comment: post the full code of this error. you are doing something wrong. `prediction` should get as input the same samples (rows/lines) as in the variable `var_test`. What is the [14,2], 1 sample with 2 features OR 2 samples with 1 feature. read the sklearn documentation and their examples.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is addressing **LinearRegression()** and **mean_squared_error()** metric.

```
  from sklearn import linear_model
  from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

  variables_train, variables_test, result_train, result_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(variables, results, test_size=0.2)

  regression = linear_model.LinearRegression()

  regression.fit(variables_train, result_train)

  prediction = regression.predict(variables_test)

  mean_squared_score = mean_squared_error(result_test, prediction)

  print("MEAN SQUARED SCORE", mean_squared_score)
```

PLEASE NOTE: I left some question's details I think have no impact on the issue of using regression model evaluation metrics.